# Необходимо к существующему URL дописывать в конец строку, подскажите как это реализовать

Tags: javascript, url

Необходимо к существующему URL  дописывать в конец строку, подскажите как это реализовать

Comment: `let существующий_URL = 'https://google.com/'; let строка = 'maps'; существующий_URL += строка;`

Answer (score 0):

Так

```
location.href += '?search=1'
```

Либо так, если перезагрузка страницы не нужна

```
history.pushState({}, '', location.href + '?search=1')
```